# Preserve Date Created when Exporting Photos from iPad to External Drive

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, metadata, photos, ipad

#### Desired behavior

I want to be able to view photos through an external solid state drive with their Date shown as when the photo was taken.

#### Current behavior

I `select` a photo in **Photos**, click `Save to Files`, choose the `external drive`, and `save`. Then when I navigate to **Files** and browse, the copied photos *show the current date, not when they were taken*. This makes me think the photos are literally copied as new files, instead of moved with their metadata (i.e. date taken).

#### Debugging so far

The most significant step I've taken to debug so far is verifying that when I move a photo from my Macbook to the hard drive and view the photo in Files on the iPad (with the hard drive attached to the iPad), it shows the correct date in files (when the photo was taken). This proves Files has the capability to read the metadata correctly.

I've tried lots of other things, browsed, etc, but none of it has been relevant after verifying the Date Created metadata is lost on copying from Photos through the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

Download "exiftool", then study this (Bash/Terminal) commandline, which renames image files with given extensions in "$dir", placing the renamed files in "$todir".

```
( 
  exiftool -v -r -ext JPG -ext NEF -ext TIF -ext PNG -d "$todir" \
  '-filename<${createdate}_\
             ${model;tr/ /_/}-\
             ${ShutterCount;s/^.*(....)$/$1/}.\
             ${filetypeextension}' \
    "$dir"   
) 2>&1
```

The files will have names reflecting creation date, camera model, camera's shuttercount - and with retained file name extension.
*Camera model name gets spaces replaced by underline -characters, only the last four digits in the shuttercount will be copied.*

You WILL most likely have to study Exiftools docs and some examples from the net to get to fully understand what all that does.

*Note: This is the base command in the script I personally use to move files from my digital camera memory cards into the "photo stash" I have.*

***The backslashes are were added for readability, I hope they don't destroy this; you might have to join the content inside the parenthese onto a single line; that is how it is in my script.***